# Erro no download de PDF: unknown protocol: c

Tags: java, jsf

Estou tentando fazer o download de um arquivo PDF, utilizando JSF..

Porém ao executar o método, a exception é lançada.

Meu Método:

```
public void download(String pathUrl) throws IOException {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

        response.reset();   // Algum filtro pode ter configurado alguns cabeçalhos no buffer de antemão. Queremos livrar-se deles, senão ele pode colidir.
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");  // Define apenas o tipo de conteúdo, Utilize se necessário ServletContext#getMimeType() para detecção automática com base em nome de arquivo. 
        OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        // Lê o conteúdo do PDF
        URL url = new URL(pathUrl);
        InputStream pdfInputStream = url.openStream();

        // Lê o conteúdo do PDF e grava para saída
        byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = pdfInputStream.read(bytesBuffer)) > 0) {
            responseOutputStream.write(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }    
        responseOutputStream.flush();

        // Fecha os streams
        pdfInputStream.close();
        responseOutputStream.close();         
        facesContext.responseComplete();         
    }
```

A Exceção Lançada:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c   at
>   java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)   at java.net.URL.(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.URL.(Unknown Source)  at
>   br.com.cogerh.template.controller.RelatorioBean.download(RelatorioBean.java:137)
>     at
>   br.com.cogerh.template.controller.RelatorioBean.gerarCapa(RelatorioBean.java:74)
>     at
>   br.com.cogerh.template.controller.RelatorioBean.gerarRelatorio(RelatorioBean.java:62)
>     at
>   br.com.cogerh.template.controller.RelatorioBean.init(RelatorioBean.java:49)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:396)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1505)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334)
>     at br.com.cogerh.template.util.ViewScope.get(ViewScope.java:23)     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)    at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)  at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1864)
>     at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1860)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:461)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:169)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema da seguinte maneira:

Adicionei a String

```
file:///
```

Ao meu pathURL, Ficando assim o método:

```
public void download(String pathUrl) throws IOException {
    pathUrl = "file:///"+pathUrl;
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    response.reset();   // Algum filtro pode ter configurado alguns cabeçalhos no buffer de antemão. Queremos livrar-se deles, senão ele pode colidir.
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");  // Define apenas o tipo de conteúdo, Utilize se necessário ServletContext#getMimeType() para detecção automática com base em nome de arquivo. 
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    // Lê o conteúdo do PDF
    URL url = new URL(pathUrl);
    InputStream pdfInputStream = url.openStream();

    // Lê o conteúdo do PDF e grava para saída
    byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = pdfInputStream.read(bytesBuffer)) > 0) {
        responseOutputStream.write(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }    
    responseOutputStream.flush();

    // Fecha os streams
    pdfInputStream.close();
    responseOutputStream.close();         
    facesContext.responseComplete();         
}
```